# Active window screenshot using javascript code?

Tags: javascript, screenshot, active-window

I am trying to get a snapshot of desktop application(developed in html5+javascript) .I know in java I can take the screenshot of active window.But is there any way /scripts using which I can take active window screenshots?Suggest me the approach other than html2canvas

Thanks in advance.